# Animation Ignoring Initial Values (animation-fill-mode)

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

### What I have done...

I am currently in the process of writing a script that will animate elements as they come into the users viewport, much like WOW.js.

However, I am experiencing some weird behaviour with the elements that I intend to animate. Instead of animating from the first step of the keyframe, it is ignoring any styles that are not set on the original element.

Consider this:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#some_element').addClass('animated fade_in_down');
}, 500);
```

```css
/* The element I intend to animate */
#some_element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0; /* I set the initial opacity */
  /* NOTE - I have not set transform:translateY(-20px); */
}

/* The animation classes */
.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both /* I think this is the important part */
}

.fade_in_down {
  animation-name: fade_in_down
}

@keyframes fade_in_down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_element">
```

### My Issue...

So, if you run the above snippet, you will find that the animation works as it is intended. As in, it fades in and it translates 20px...

My issue is, on my site, it is ignoring the `transform` property unless I explicitly set it in the original `#some_element` styles.

Unless I do the following, I only see the `opacity` animate:

```
#some_element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  transform:translateY(-20px); /* I have added the initial transform value */
}
```

Why is this? Why does it work on other sites without having to set the initial `transform` value? Can anyone elaborate as to what could possibly be causing this?

I am ***using a CSS minifier*** which is stripping out the `%` symbol after the `0` within the `@keyframes` rule. Could this be the reason? Is it invalid to strip out the `%` symbol?

*Unfortunately, I am unable to post my entire code as this is just a snippet from a very large web application. I am hoping that someone may know what is going on without needing to see my entire code...*

Comment: A wild guess because unless we see the actual problem, we can't say much but have you tried adding the `animated` class to the element by default and adding the `fade-in-down` alone only when needed?

Comment: @Harry I haven't tried that but I imagine that wouldn't fix it as this is the exact same method many others use...

Comment: It's only a shot in the dark because the code provided doesn't simulate the issue and the one where the issue is can't be seen by us.

Comment: @Harry Can we privately chat and I can post the link for you?

Comment: I don't mind Ben but I don't think SO has a private chat feature. Whatever you post would probably be visible to anybody who accesses the chat page.

Comment: @Harry It does have a private chat feature, you just have to send enough messages in the comments and then it suggests it... haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

The problem is either because of how you've coded the `@keyframes` rules in your actual CSS file (or) because of how your minifier is minifying the code.

The below is the output CSS that I can see in your minified CSS file. As you can see in `@keyframes`, the `%` is missing after the `0`. The percentage is mandatory and since it is absent the UA is ignoring the properties set under it completely and so the original negative `translateY` is never applied on it. Since the original transform is never applied, it doesn't slide-down and just appears.

From the [W3C Specs for Animation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes): (emphasis is mine)

> Note that the percentage unit specifier must be used on percentage values. Therefore, ***‘0’ is an invalid keyframe selector***.

The `opacity` works because you have `.reveal-on-scroll` which is forcing in the `opacity: 0` on the element.

```css
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}
.fade_in_down {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade_in_down;
  animation-name: fade_in_down
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade_in_down {
  0 { /* note the missing % symbol */
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}
@keyframes fade_in_down {
  0 { /* note the missing % symbol */
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}
```

---

**Demonstration:**

Just for demonstration of this, I've added two elements in the below demo where one has an animation with `%` before `0` in `@keyframes` rule and other without it (`%`). One whose keyframe is written as `0%` will slide down properly whereas the one whose keyframe is written as `0` will just appear.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#some_element').addClass('animated fade_in_down');
  $('#some_element2').addClass('animated fade_in_down2');
}, 500);
```

```css
#some_element,
#some_element2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}
.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}
.fade_in_down {
  animation-name: fade_in_down
}
@keyframes fade_in_down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

/* this is how the minified output in your CSS file is */

.fade_in_down2 {
  animation-name: fade_in_down2
}
@keyframes fade_in_down2 {
  0 {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_element"></div>
<div id="some_element2"></div>
```

---

**Solution:**

If the symbol is missing in your original CSS, add it in. If the minifier is stripping it out then see how to avoid that. Unfortunately I don't know much about it.

Comment: Thank you so much Harry! I am not surprised I didnt realise this as I have been using the same minifier for over four years! I wish I could upvote this 5 times to thank you for the time you put in!!! How were you able to see the code in the `keyframes`? Is there a way to see it with Inspect Element?

Comment: @BenCarey: You're welcome mate. I just picked the link to your cached CSS file (the `css.yoursitename/_cache/*`) and opened it in the browser :)

Comment: Yup @BenCarey. Its fairly simple (unlike minified JS). You'd just have to search with the animation's name :)